# не выводится список статей через шаблон

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

вот базовый url:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

вот url приложения:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'question'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),

]
```

вот views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Question
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5],
    return render(request, 'polls/list.html', {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list})

def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." )
```

вот list.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block title %} 2 шаблон {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    {% if latest_question_list %}
        {% for a in latest_question_list %}
            <a href="{% url 'question:detail' q.id %}">{{ q.question_text }}</a>
#{{ question.id }}/">
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        НЕТ НИЧЕГО
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

вот base.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>{% block title %} 1 шаблон {% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}



{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

по идее должен был выводить список статей, но на сайте выводит ошибку и пишет "Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$']", я не понимаю почему я написал норм аргументы, а сайт выводит такое вместо списка

Структура такова Django-mysite-polls(приложение)
tempates-base.html и polls(папка)- list.html

Comment: у вас урл приложения:
path('polls/', include('polls.urls'))
а урл в шаблоне:
<a href="{% url 'question:detail' q.id %}">{{ q.question_text }}</a>

почему вы обращаетесь question:detail если апп называется polls? Вам надо приложение переименовать в question

Answer (score 0):

Что такое **q** в шаблоне list.html? Цикл вы назвали **a**. Переименуйте цикл в q или замените все q на название цикла, где выводятся ссылки. Это будет выглядеть вот так:

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block title %} 2 шаблон {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    {% if latest_question_list %}
        {% for a in latest_question_list %}
            <a href="{% url 'question:detail' a.id %}">{{ a.question_text }}</a>
#{{ question.id }}/">
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        НЕТ НИЧЕГО
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Это первое, а во вторых: почему в ссылке в теге url вы указали `question:detail`,если в base url вы подключали polls?